# How do I implement multiple traits for one type and choose between the traits?

Tags: inheritance, rust, multiple-inheritance

How would you typically handle something like this in Rust?

```py
class Base(Model):
    def do_something(self, x):
        return {"base": x * 2}

class A(Model):
    extend = Base
    def do_something(self, x):
        res = super(A, self).do_something()
        res['test'] = x
        return res

class B(Model):
    extend = Base
    def do_something(self, x):
        if x > 5:
            res = super(B, self).do_something()
        else:
            res = {}
        return res

obj = Base()
obj.do_something(1)
>> {}
obj.do_something(6)
>> {'test': 6, 'base': 12}
```

In Python, I'd have something like that where the `Base` class is continuously extended using a metaclass. You always use the `Base` class and the other ones are just syntactic sugar to extend the `Base` class.

As you can see, in the body of `B.do_something` the order in which the methods are called is controlled by the body of the function and not in sequence so it's not possible to simply store a list of functions and then call them in sequence.

In Python, most of the logic is hidden behind a metaclass but the idea is to offer a single place for an extension developer adding methods to a model to not have to know how some other module also appended itself to the same model.

For example, the `Base` behaves a bit like a proxy. Whenever another class subclasses it, it will create a new type based on the top type. When you call a method it's doing something like `return getattr(self._inner, name)(args)` and uses normal inheritance in Python to get the `super`. When it extends it, all it does is `self.top = type(self.name, (self.top,), args...)` but since Rust doesn't have inheritance, I'm not sure how it can be done.

Is there a way to achieve something close this this in Rust without making the code completely unreadable?

As I understand one way to achieve that would be to create functor objects

like

```
struct Command {
   name: String,
   super: &command: Command,
   func: Fn (&Object, &Command
, ArgumentMap) -> Any
}

struct Object {
   name: String,
   commands: Map<Command>,
}

impl Object {
  fn insert_command(&self, command: Command) {
    let super_command = self.commands.get(command.name)
    if (super_command) {
      command.super = super_command
    }
    self.commands.remove(super_command.name)
    self.commands.set(command.name, command)
  }

  fn call(&self, name:String, args: ArgumentMap) -> Any {
    let command = self.commands.get(command.name)
    (command.func)(self, command.super, args)
  }

  fn extend(extension: Map<String, ?closure?>) {
     // for each key add a command
  }
}

user = Object {
    name: "user",
    commands: Map<Command> {}
}

user.extend({
  "do_something": |self, super, args| {
     // change args
     let new_args = self.call("change_args", args)
     let ret = (super.func)(self, super.super, new_args)
     // do something with ret
  },
})

user.extend({
    "do_something": |self, super, args| {
       // will call method previously defined above
       let ret = (super.func)(self, super.super, args)
       ret
    }
})
```

That's pretty much how I'd do that. `Object` is just a plain object that is there to store the functions as necessary. It can be made better by making `super` as a callable that only take `args` as argument by encapsulating the (self, next super method).

This is how I'd do it as I don't know if this kind of thing could be done without implementing an object-like structure. This is all going to be executed at runtime but I guess it's not possible to do much otherwise because there is a need for reflection if something is supposed to call it externally using a JSON request. Let's imagine one of the entrypoint is a webserver that receive the method to be called on a model. As I understand, Rust doesn't offer reflection so it only make sense to do it like that.

Comment: This is not possible in Rust. Either a type impls a trait (and then there is no ambiguity regarding which trait a method comes from) or it doesn't. You could have a trait `Authentication` with methods `authenticate_oath`, `authenticate_pam` etc., have their default implementation return `Err(AuthenticationError::NotImplemented)`, and have the `Authenticator` try each method in sequence.

Comment: *I'd call `super` to check the `super` method* — I guarantee you that there's a better way of writing this in Python that doesn't use inheritance. Once you figure that out, you can probably write that in Rust.

Comment: @user2722968 yes but how do you call each method in sequence if you don't know how they're called? Also that could work for auth but in other cases, I need to compose the result of the super call.

Comment: @Shepmaster care to elaborate? This was an example but there are cases I need to compose the result of the super call. For example a method that create some default data. One module add certain default while an other module add other default. The method would be called like `prepare_data` and each module combine its own data with the result of the super call.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix that doesn't require inheritance, just a vector of things that are called in sequence. I cannot elaborate because your question is overly broad. You are likely suffering from the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and you've described how you think you should solve it as opposed to focusing on what your end goal is. There's not enough crumbs of context for me to even begin to speculate.

Comment: For example, if you ask "how do I have a superclass in Rust?" the answer will be "you can't". If you ask about solving the problem and clearly describe that problem, then we might be able to point towards solutions.

Comment: @Shepmaster concrete enough now?

Comment: You mean [like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f935570a48015cb09da2bb50f7e8f410)?